# Installing several applications at once from Inno Setup

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I'm pretty new to Inno Setup. I created a fairly simple installer (and it wasn't hard at all), that consisted of one application. I wanted to know if Inno Setup is a suitable choice for creating an installer, that would consist of several applications, that have their own installers (as far as I understand, these installers could be run from Inno Setup). And is there an option (probably related to writing some Delphi code), that would let user choosing what apps need to be installed (with checkboxes or something like that). I understand that it's not really a concrete question (though a code sample or a full answer would be appreciated), I just don't want to spend too much time setting this tool (though I liked Inno Setup), if it doesn't meet my needs.

Comment: You could simply add each app as a `Component`, which can be selected from `ComponentsList` (as a Check Boxes) - you can set specific operations for each Component - e.g. epecific files to be installed, specific registry entries, etc. 
If you want to specify specific location for each app, then it might be a little tricky.

Comment: The other way is to Compile all installers (with `DestDir: "{tmp}"`) by your installer and add in `RUN` section as options. But that is not the best solution as all installers will be extracted to `{tmp}` and if you would like your installer to delete them after you would have to `waituntilterminated` combined with `deleteafterinstall` in FILES section. That is commonly used for 3rdparty apps like VC Redists, PhysX, DirectX and other additional apps needed by main app to run.

Comment: @RobeN Thanks for the answer. Could NSIS be a better option for this task?

Comment: In this case both scripts are similar. In NSIS you can create dependencies easier (if 1st selected then 3rd always selected, etc) but IS is faster when it comes to build components section itself and it's clearer (but that is only my opinion). I don't know exactly what you want to combine/embed though, so I cannot make a clear statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An Inno Setup can include other setups and extract/run them on any condition, including dependancies (not) existing, user prompts and `[Components]`/`[Tasks]`.

You can use a normal `[Files]` entry to extract it into `{tmp}` and a `[Run]` entry to run it.

If the other setups are external to the Inno setup, skip the `[Files]` entry and use `{src}\BlahSetup.exe` for the `[Run]` entry.