# Inno setup: creating a software suite installer

Tags: inno-setup

I want to create an installer with inno setup that installs several .exe at once. I have checked other posts here like this [Installing several applications at once from Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352525/installing-several-applications-at-once-from-inno-setup) but I still have some doubts.

In first place I did it creating a separated installer file for each application and joining all of them in a final installer. It works, but I don't like how it looks.

Then I have tried to include all the applications in the [files] section of a single script, and it works but then I have the problem with the icon and the group name. I want three icons to be created, one for each application i am installing.

I am sure the solution is simple but I haven't got it yet, so thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So create three entries in the `[Icons]` section, one for each application.